# Electron JS mainwindow is not defined

Tags: javascript, electron

When I run this and click on the submenu item for "ports" I keep getting this error than mainWindow is not defined. Why is that? You can see I have it defined in the main.js file so why doesn't this register in the menu.js file?

The end goal here is that when I click on the correct port in the menu I can send that value to the renderer so that I can make SerialPort connect to right the right serial port.

**Main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1200, height: 600 })

  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })

  require('./menu/menu')
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**Menu.js**

```
const { Menu, ipcMain, webContents } = require('electron')
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app

const template = [
    {
        label: 'Edit',
        submenu: [
            { role: 'undo' },
            { role: 'redo' }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Ports',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'select port',
                submenu: []
            }
        ]
    },
    { label: 'Help' }
]

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    template.unshift({
        label: app.getName(),
        submenu: [
            { role: 'about' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'services' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'hide' },
            { role: 'hideothers' },
            { role: 'unhide' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'quit' }
        ]
    })
}

ipcMain.on('serialPorts', (event, data) => {
    let portsSubMenu = []
    data.forEach((port) => {
        portsSubMenu.push({
            label: port.comName,
            click(menuItem, browserWindow, event) {
                mainWindow.webContents.send('portSelected', port)
            }
        })
    })
    template[2].submenu[0].submenu = portsSubMenu
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
})
```

Comment: change `let mainWindow` to `var mainWindow`

Comment: Yeah, that didn't quite do the trick.

Comment: What you do get when you console.log() or set a break point in the click handler?

Comment: I actually just resorted to not trying to have the menu template in a separate js file. I just included the code for the menu directly in the main.js file. and it's working great. I wish I knew why that was not working though.

Answer (score 2):

Each file is a separate module, with a separate context. Each and every variable that you define inside one module, stays in that module and never leaks outside (unless you specifically make it to). If you want to access a variable from one module in the other one, you need to either export it or pass it as an argument to the corresponding method from another module.

It wasn't working because you were trying to access `mainWindow` from `menu.js`, and, as the error said, you did not have it defined there.